# how do I go about tracking down DEPRECATION WARNING related to Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm pretty new to Rails. I keep seeing these deprecation warnings when I start my app:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: ref is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 3.2. 
(called from <top (required)> at D:/dev/AquaticKodiak/config/application.rb:12)
DEPRECATION WARNING: new is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 3.2. 
(called from <top (required)> at D:/dev/AquaticKodiak/config/application.rb:12)
```

OK, what's on line 12? This:

`Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)`

Hmm, that's not really narrowing it down. This says to me that one of the gems that's related to my app is using a keyword that will disappear soon. I'd really like to figure out which one. All the gems in my gemfile are using the `>= [version]` syntax, except the ones that are coming from github. I suspect that the github stuff is causing this, but how do I find out which project it is? Pulling code and searching for the keyword looks like work -- is there an easier way?

Comment: You could do a binary search to find the offender. Cut out half of your gems, test, and if the problem's gone, focus on the other half. If not, cut that in half again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Rails deprecation warning is pretty unhelpful here. It has a complete callstack that could help you find the out of date gem, but is filtering the result to return the first non-framework point in the callstack, in this case application.rb.

To find the offending gem I would grab the full callstack at ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn, which is defined at line 10 of activesupport/lib/active_support/deprecation/reporting.rb.

If you have [Pry](http://pry.github.com/) installed (recommended) then add a conditional binding at line 11 of reporting.rb:

```
binding.pry if message =~ /ref is deprecated/
```

Then inspect caller.

If you post a Gemfile I can take a look for you.

Comment: FYI, the line numbers will change between Rails releases. Put inside of the `warn` method, below `callstack ||= caller(2)`. I also had to require pry like so: `require 'pry'; binding.pry`, and inspect `callstack` to get the trace I needed.